# a feature that gives video call inside the xamarin project

Tags: video-streaming, xamarin, facetime

why doesn't xamarin support facetime, if I want to have video call within the application what would be the best 3rd party API that supports xamarin

Comment: There is no Facetime API.  Xamarin cannot support something that doesn't exist.  Questions asking for tool recommendations are off topic on SO.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but can you please direct me what should be done for video streaming for ios and android apps.

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/574/video-streaming-conferencing/p1

Comment: Thank you Jason, do you know if there are any samples apps that already there?

Comment: ABPersonViewController is available xamarin also, allowsActions property will bring facetime which solves video streaming right. why do we need to use 3rd party like tokbox. please suggest

Comment: if you just want to initiate a FaceTime call, you can probably do that.  But there is no API to allow any fine grained control.  And you specifically asked for 3rd party tool recommendations.

Comment: Another 3rd party API: http://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink